# Lightning accordion

Tags: lightning

As of now, when we use lightning:accordion, we will not be able to close a section. The first section will close when we open second section. But I have a requirement where I have to close the first section without opening the second one. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Lightning Accordion with multiple sections open](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:accordion/example#lightningcomponentdemo:exampleAccordionMultiple). Which allow us to close the section without need to open another one

You need to just set an attribute to enable this.

```
<lightning:accordion
        allowMultipleSectionsOpen="true"
        onsectiontoggle="{! c.handleSectionToggle }"
        activeSectionName="{! v.activeSections }"
    >
```

[image]